# WebTiledLayer in ArcGIS API for JavaScript fails in Chrome but works in other browsers?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, chrome

In the Firefox browser can be displayed in the chrome nothing is displayed in the opera does not show templatepicker

[image]
chrome
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Landuse</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.21/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.21/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #header {
        border: solid 2px #462d44;
        background: #fff;
        color: #444;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    #map {
        padding: 1px;
        border: solid 2px #444;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    #rightPane {
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
        width: 228px;
    }
    #LocateButton {
        position: absolute;
        top: 95px;
        left: 20px;
        z-index: 50;
    }
    #HomeButton {
        position: absolute;
        top: 195px;
        left: 20px;
        z-index: 50;
    }
    .templatePicker {
        border: solid 2px #444;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.21/"></script>
<script>
    var map;
    require([
        "esri/map",
        "esri/dijit/HomeButton",
        "esri/dijit/LocateButton",
        "esri/layers/WebTiledLayer",
        "esri/toolbars/draw",
        "esri/toolbars/edit",
        "esri/graphic",
        "esri/config",

        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",

        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",

        "esri/dijit/editing/TemplatePicker",

        "dojo/_base/array",
        "dojo/_base/event",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dijit/registry",

        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (Map,HomeButton,LocateButton,WebTiledLayer, Draw, Edit, Graphic, esriConfig,
                 FeatureLayer,
                 SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol,
                 TemplatePicker,
                 arrayUtils, event, lang, parser, registry) {
        parser.parse();

        // refer to "Using the Proxy Page" for more information:  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/ags_proxy.html
        esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";

        // This service is for development and testing purposes only. We recommend that you create your own geometry service for use within your applications.
        esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("https://118.89.184.239:6443/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer");

        map = new Map("map", {
            "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326},

        });


        map.on("layers-add-result", initEditing);
        var tileInfo = new esri.layers.TileInfo({
            "rows": 256,
            "cols": 256,
            "compressionQuality": 0,
            "origin": {
                "x": -180,
                "y": 90
            },
            "spatialReference": {
                "wkid": 4326
            },
            "lods": [
                {"level": 2, "resolution": 0.3515625, "scale": 147748796.52937502},
                {"level": 3, "resolution": 0.17578125, "scale": 73874398.264687508},
                {"level": 4, "resolution": 0.087890625, "scale": 36937199.132343754},
                {"level": 5, "resolution": 0.0439453125, "scale": 18468599.566171877},
                {"level": 6, "resolution": 0.02197265625, "scale": 9234299.7830859385},
                {"level": 7, "resolution": 0.010986328125, "scale": 4617149.8915429693},
                {"level": 8, "resolution": 0.0054931640625, "scale": 2308574.9457714846},
                {"level": 9, "resolution": 0.00274658203125, "scale": 1154287.4728857423},
                {"level": 10, "resolution": 0.001373291015625, "scale": 577143.73644287116},
                {"level": 11, "resolution": 0.0006866455078125, "scale": 288571.86822143558},
                {"level": 12, "resolution": 0.00034332275390625, "scale": 144285.93411071779},
                {"level": 13, "resolution": 0.000171661376953125, "scale": 72142.967055358895},
                {"level": 14, "resolution": 8.58306884765625e-005, "scale": 36071.483527679447},
                {"level": 15, "resolution": 4.291534423828125e-005, "scale": 18035.741763839724},
                {"level": 16, "resolution": 2.1457672119140625e-005, "scale": 9017.8708819198619},
                {"level": 17, "resolution": 1.0728836059570313e-005, "scale": 4508.9354409599309},
                {"level": 18, "resolution": 5.3644180297851563e-006, "scale": 2254.4677204799655}
            ]
        });
        //底图
        var baseMap = new WebTiledLayer("http://${subDomain}.tianditu.com/img_c/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=img&STYLE=default&TILEMATRIXSET=c&TILECOL=${col}&TILEROW=${row}&TILEMATRIX=${level}&FORMAT=tiles",
            //"http://${subDomain}.tianditu.com/DataServer?T=vec_c&X=${col}&Y=${row}&L=${level}", {
            {
                "copyright": "Tianditu",
                "id": "Tianditu",
                "subDomains": ["t0", "t1", "t2"],
                "tileInfo": tileInfo
            });
        //底图标注
        var baseMapMarker = new WebTiledLayer("http://${subDomain}.tianditu.com/cia_c/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=cia&STYLE=default&TILEMATRIXSET=c&TILECOL=${col}&TILEROW=${row}&TILEMATRIX=${level}&FORMAT=tiles",     //"http://${subDomain}.tianditu.com/DataServer?T=cva_c&X=${col}&Y=${row}&L=${level}", {
            {
                "copyright": "Tianditu",
                "id": "Tianditu2",
                "subDomains": ["t0", "t1", "t2"],
                "tileInfo": tileInfo
            });
        map.addLayer(baseMap);
        map.addLayer(baseMapMarker);

        var landusePolygonLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://118.89.184.239:6443/arcgis/rest/services/土地信息/FeatureServer/0", {
            mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
            outFields: ["*"]
        });
        console.log(landusePolygonLayer)

        map.addLayer(landusePolygonLayer);




        function initEditing(evt) {
            console.log("initEditing", evt);
            // var map = this;
            var currentLayer = null;
            var layers = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function (result) {
                return result.layer;
            });
            console.log("layers", layers);

            var editToolbar = new Edit(map);
            editToolbar.on("deactivate", function (evt) {
                currentLayer.applyEdits(null, [evt.graphic], null);
            });

            arrayUtils.forEach(layers, function (layer) {
                var editingEnabled = false;
                layer.on("dbl-click", function (evt) {
                    event.stop(evt);
                    if (editingEnabled === false) {
                        editingEnabled = true;
                        editToolbar.activate(Edit.EDIT_VERTICES, evt.graphic);
                    } else {
                        currentLayer = this;
                        editToolbar.deactivate();
                        editingEnabled = false;
                    }
                });

                layer.on("click", function (evt) {
                    event.stop(evt);
                    if (evt.ctrlKey === true || evt.metaKey === true) {  //delete feature if ctrl key is depressed
                        layer.applyEdits(null, null, [evt.graphic]);
                        currentLayer = this;
                        editToolbar.deactivate();
                        editingEnabled = false;
                    }
                });
            });

            var templatePicker = new TemplatePicker({
                featureLayers: layers,
                rows: "auto",
                columns: 2,
                grouping: true,
                style: "height: auto; overflow: auto;"
            }, "templatePickerDiv");

            templatePicker.startup();

            var drawToolbar = new Draw(map);

            var selectedTemplate;
            templatePicker.on("selection-change", function () {
                if (templatePicker.getSelected()) {
                    selectedTemplate = templatePicker.getSelected();
                }
                switch (selectedTemplate.featureLayer.geometryType) {
                    case "esriGeometryPoint":
                        drawToolbar.activate(Draw.POINT);
                        break;
                    case "esriGeometryPolyline":
                        drawToolbar.activate(Draw.POLYLINE);
                        break;
                    case "esriGeometryPolygon":
                        drawToolbar.activate(Draw.POLYGON);
                        break;
                }
            });

            drawToolbar.on("draw-end", function (evt) {
                drawToolbar.deactivate();
                editToolbar.deactivate();
                // var newAttributes = lang.mixin({}, selectedTemplate.template.prototype.attributes);
                var newAttributes = {
                    "AREA": 1500,
                    "AUTHOR":"test"
                };
                var newGraphic = new Graphic(evt.geometry, null, newAttributes);
                console.log(newGraphic.geometry)
                selectedTemplate.featureLayer.applyEdits([newGraphic], null, null);
            });
        }
        //定位到自己
        geoLocate = new LocateButton({
            map: map
        }, "LocateButton");
        geoLocate.startup();
        //回到一开始
        var home = new HomeButton({
            map: map
        }, "HomeButton");
        home.startup();


        map.centerAndZoom(new esri.geometry.Point({
            "x": 118.81,
            "y": 32.08,
            "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326}
        }), 3);
        console.log(map.extent);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="gutters:true, design:'headline'"
 style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="header" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
    请在此界面上选择您的土地，单击右侧符号开始绘图，双击结束，CTRL+鼠标右键进行删除
</div>
<div id="search"></div>
<div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
    <div id="LocateButton"></div>
    <div id="HomeButton"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; right:20px; top:10px; z-Index:999;">
        <button>按钮</button>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane"
             data-dojo-props="title:'Switch Basemap', closable:false, open:false">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="width:380px; height:280px; overflow:auto;">
                <div id="basemapGallery"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rightPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'">
    <div id="templatePickerDiv"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: merin, welcome to gis.stackexchange.  Could you try simplify the example?  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also, does the browser console show any error messages to help identify the problem?

Comment: If you remove the `$` in `TILEMATRIX=${level}` then it works in all browsers. Strange...